# The X & Y coordinates for points on a bell curve / normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

In Short:
I want to give a formula the X coordinate and get the Y coordinate from matching a bell curve. Is this possible?

In Detail:
I'm trying to program a market simulation and to get a product's "desirability" I'd like to use a bell curve. *(This is a math question, trust me!)*

When I graphed two S-Curves (one mirrored), I basically had a pointy bell curve. In this graph, X is 'how much' (price and quality) something is, from 1-100, from low-price & low-quality to high-price & high-quality. Y is the 'desire' consumers have for the product based on price vs quality. Y's values are a variables that will change, X's values will always be the same. One will not become thirty, and there's always the same total points.

What I'm wanting to do is plug in to a "magic formula" X (price vs quality) and get Y (desirability), based on a bell curve and the numbers I feed it to adjust the curve itself.

It seems like bell curves only give you points away from the median or percents around the curve. I've searched and searched, but turned up nothing on how to get the coordinates (x,y) on points of a bell curve. **Any help would be appreciated.**

I'm about to just fake the whole thing and have two arrays of numbers, and then adjust the second set to meet changing markets. I really want to use a bell curve because it's so simple and dynamic compared to fudging the whole thing.

Comment: If you look at the normal distribution on Wikipedia, you'll get the formula you want.  If you don't care whether it's a PDF or not (that is, whether the area under the curve is one), then you can scale it however you like: Assuming a mean of 50, and a standard deviation of $\sigma$, the equation is then $y = Ke^{-(x-50)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$, where $K$ is the height at the peak.

Comment: Note that this will give positive values of desirability away outside the range $0-100$.  That's because the normal distribution has positive value along the entire real axis.

Comment: This is perfect, I can't thank you enough. I get this. I understand this. Thank you! 
Also, I have to apologize, I didn't think wikipedia had it much less explained it. I was using sites that explained how normal distributions work and following along. I understood them, but none of the sites had what I wanted. 
A really dumb moment there for me. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. :)